# React hook form not catching value change in field array

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I would like to watch a field in a field array with useWatch hook. Full example can bee seen in the codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-usefieldarray-watch-forked-yiux0m?file=/src/index.js). I have tried to catch the value change in a child component of the field array like this:

```
     {fields.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <li key={item.id}>
            <Input item={item} index={index} />
            <button type="button" onClick={() => remove(index)}>
              Delete
            </button>
          </li>
        );
      })}
```

And in Input field component I would like to watch for a change of the vale of the input field:

```
const Input = ({ item, index }) => {
  const { control } = useFormContext();
  const value = useWatch({ control, name: `test.${index}.name` });

  console.log("value ", value);
  return <input name={`test[${index}].name`} defaultValue={`${item.name}`} />;
};
```

But, as you can see in the codesandox if you write anything in the input field, useWatch won't catch it. It only catches if the field was appended or removed from the field array, but not if a field of an item has changed. Is there a way of catching that?

Comment: You can just attach an event handler directly to the input (`onChange={ ... }`)

Comment: I am aware of that, but I wanted to use useWatch